# Handling chrome.storage Array Size Limits

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm dealing with Chrome Storage API for extensions, and I'm not sure about how to properly handle storage size limits.

Say I have an array which keeps growing (which is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191731/how-do-i-efficiently-add-items-to-an-array-in-the-chrome-storage-api) I have about performance). I would need to check if I'm out of space. I know I can compare [the actual size](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#method-StorageArea-getBytesInUse) with QUOTA_BYTES, and many other properties analogically.

Concerning the growing array, I thought about two options:

- when `chrome.storage.{StorageArea}.set()` is fired I can check if there was an error. I would then check if I'm out of storage and do something. Maybe I should consider using an index to achieve some kind of FIFO queue.
- (I can't remember)

These are my `get` and `push` functions, in which I'm not sure how I should implement the fail callback function, neither redesign the way the array grows.

```
var storageArea = chrome.storage.sync;
var storageArray = {

    get: function(key, callback) {
        storageArea.get(key, function(obj) {
            var values = obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ? obj[key] : [];
            callback(values);
        })
    },

    push: function(key, value, success, fail) {
        storageArea.get(key, function(obj) {
            var values = obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ? obj[key] : [];
            values.push(value);

            var thekey = key;
            var myobj = {}
            myobj[key] = values;

            storageArea.set(myobj, function() {
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError)
                    typeof fail === 'function' && fail(chrome.runtime.lastError);
                else
                    typeof success === 'function' && success();
            });
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Quota is not the only limit for `sync` storage - you're just as likely to run into throttling. That said, I'm unsure what your question is.

Comment: I believe that the question isn't hard to understand Xan. I know there are many other limits, but I need to solve one in a proper way first in order to replicate that on the others analogically

Comment: Your explanations are not hard to understand at all; but can you please formulate your _question_ more clearly? What do you need _answered_?

Comment: How I should handle that limits, i.e. in my code. Specially a growing array.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your code not handling storage limits. It will properly `fail()` if you run into this limit. The error will tell you if it's quota limit or something else. How you deal with that (obviously, retrying would probably not help) depends on your task. So yes - I still fail to understand what kind of answer you are looking for. Maybe we're missing information here on what your goal is.

Comment: Well, I may be confusing. The growing array is a clear problem, because I don't know how (or if I) should implement some kind of FIFO queue considering I'm pushing values in such a very inefficient way, which is the only way I found. Speaking about the other errors, there's no way to know which one fired, because as far as i know `chrome.runtime.lastError` is a message, not a code, and they are not documented.. I can't even test my error handling, I guess I would need to push it to its limits in that case

Comment: When did not being documented stop anyone.. There is `StorageArea.getBytesInUse` function though.

Comment: I have an awful growing array. What should I do?

Comment: Not use `chrome.storage.sync`. Quotas are low and inflexible. As Google puts it, _"`chrome.storage` is not a big truck. It's a series of tubes. And if you don't understand, those tubes can be filled, and if they are filled when you put your message in, it gets in line, and it's going to be delayed by anyone that puts into that tube enormous amounts of material."_ If you really need to sync data, you'll need a 3rd-party server-based solution. If you don't, use `local` with `"unlimitedStorage"` permission.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but do you realize that even taking that extreme solution (for my purpose, in which I mentioned I could use some FIFO design) I can't just push the values to the array? Chrome uses set() requiring the whole object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76545/discussion-between-xan-and-whitenoisedb).